# textarea height is overflowing parent container

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a `div` that contains another a child `div`. In that child `div` is an `h1` tag and a `textarea` tag. I want the `h1` tag and the `textarea` to fit the height of the parent `div` but it looks like the `textarea` is being pushed out of the parent `div`.

I have tried using `box-sizing: border-box;` for the `textarea` to ensure it stays within the parent `div` and while that works for the width, it does not work for the height.

I have also been able to provide a temporary fix by making the `textarea` have a height of `87%` of the parent `div` but then if I zoom out in the browser eventually the `textarea` bleeds over the parent `div`. I have also tried putting `overflow:hidden` for the containing `div` which prevents the bleed but then I can't see the bottom portion of m `textarea`.

Ideally, I would like the `textarea` to not have a height that takes up the rest of the `div` that is not occupied by the `h1` tag. I would also prefer to not have the `textarea` borders bleed over the containing `div` at all, which has even happened when I do `overflow:hidden` which I wanted to avoid using anyway because I want the overflow to be `auto` to account for lack of word wrap.

If you inspect the snippet you'll see how the `textarea` bleeds out of the containing `div` vertically.

**EDIT**

I have considered using flexbox but I plan on having the left and right borders of the div being draggable and I'm not sure if I can use flexbox while allowing the `div` to be easily resized based on border dragging. I'm not sure if this is doable but I am open to suggestions!

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  border: solid 1px cadetBlue;
  /*grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;*/
}

.topContainer{
  display: flex; 
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px; 
  border-bottom: solid 1px cadetBlue;
}

.innerBox{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: solid 1px cadetBlue;
}

.view{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box-title{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sectionContainer{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.sectionContainer.html > div > .innerBox{
  border-left:  solid 0px transparent;
  border-right: solid 0px transparent;
}

.sectionContainer.js > div > .innerBox{
  border-right: solid 0px transparent;
}

.sectionContainer.css > div > .innerBox{
  border-right: solid 0px transparent;
}

.sectionContainer > div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='topContainer'>
<div class="sectionContainer">
              <div>
              <h2  class="box-title" style='border-left: solid 1px cadetBlue;'>JavaScript</h2>
             <textarea class="innerBox" style="width: 100%;">
        </textarea>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify you html and css drastically and use flexbox.

```
.sectionContainer // acts as a flexbox.

.sectionContainer>.box-title{
  flex: 0 0 auto; // title can not grow or shrink and has the regular height
}
.sectionContainer>.innerBox{
  flex: 1 1 auto; // textarea can grow or based on the leftover area
}
```

I animated the example to show changing the `.sectionContainer` width or height has the desired effect.

```css
.sectionContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: animateWidth 3s infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.sectionContainer>.box-title{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.sectionContainer>.innerBox{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
@keyframes animateWidth {
  0%{
    width: 100%;
  }
  25%{
    width: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  75% {
    height: 150px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionContainer">
   <h2  class="box-title">JavaScript</h2>
   <textarea class="innerBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was going to use flexbox but I want to be able to drag one side of the `div` and be able to make it wider/narrower. I am not how to adjust the flex to coincide with that.

Comment: I don't see how changing width of `sectionContainer` causes the flex values to cause an issue ( especially since the flex is used in an vertical axis )

Comment: It would be horizontal not vertical. And there are two other div's whose sizes would also need to be adjusted

Comment: I updated the answer with an animation to show that the containers width / height does not cause any issues. Can you give a clear example what the issue is you are experiencing with this?

Comment: I am creating a text editor that has 4 sections, HTML, JS, CSS and then the output view. I need to be able to drag the border of to make one side wider/taller and the other side short/narrower. So if I pull the middle portions left border (JS) to the left, then HTML should get smaller and JS should get bigger. I didn't include it in the answer as I figured I only needed the HTML/CSS related to the section

Comment: There is the resize property. I never used it and don't know if it plays nice with flexbox, but if it does it may save you from having to write any JS at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: I ended up disabling the resize as I found it hard to contain and it was hard to get it to adjust the size of the adjacent textboxes accordingly. Instead I just have the textbox fitting to the inner container. The inner container I gave absolute positioning so the top starts at a certain point in the outer container and the bottom is 0 so it doesn't overflow vertically. I also added draggable divs (bars) that trigger a mousemove event function to resize the adjacent divs accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox but don't make the textarea a flex item to avoid having issue with resize. Consider a wrapper around it.

```css
.sectionContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

.sectionContainer>.box-title{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sectionContainer>.innerBox{
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.sectionContainer>.innerBox textarea {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionContainer">
   <h2  class="box-title">JavaScript</h2>
   <div class="innerBox"><textarea ></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! However in my CSS I am disabling resize for the textareas.